# tls 1.2 handshake fails on first attempt

Tags: networking, ssl

I have a rather unique issue occurring where after a period of inactivity a TLS 1.2 connection will fail.  If the connection is reattempted it will connect successfully and will continue to connect until some period of inactivity occurs, about 1 hour.

I am not sure where to go next.

Environment is Windows Server 2012, all protocols except TLS 1.2 are disabled.

Attached is a wireshark trace of the connect, packets 1-14 are the first call and 15-39 is the second call about 6 seconds later.

[Wireshark network trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPCXJ.png)

Comment: There is no failed TLS handshake in the packet capture. Packet 1-14 show two (not one) TCP connections which are closed by the client immediately after a successful TCP handshake - but before any TLS is involved. TLS 13-39 show successful TCP handshake and data transfer, and this is the only connection which does anything with TLS. Given that the client closes the TCP connection it might be helpful is more is known about the client.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  The packets 1-14 were generated by the first call to the web site that generated a connection failure.  The next call to the site generated the remaining packets.  Why would connection not even try to setup the TLS session?

Comment: Nothing is known about the particular client which initiated the connection and how it is connected to the server (i.e. if there might be some middleboxes inferring with the traffic). So everything would just be speculation.